# Crosswalk storage limits

Tags: android, cordova, indexeddb, crosswalk-runtime

What are the storage limits when using Crosswalk? Do the same rules [as for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#temporary) apply, just in isolation of the app using Crosswalk? Or in the worst case shared global storage limits with the regular Chrome install?

Also, will Crosswalk move any data to the SD card in case the core memory fills up, e.g. an app uses say 1GB of some web database?

Been looking but really can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sharing my knowledge thoughts on the matter* - CrossWalk (CW) is just a runtime which helps get full potential of HTML5, because it supports more and advanced HTML5 features than Android's default WebView, and it helps to have a consistent UI in all Android apps, irrespective of who is handset manufacturer.

For that, app will contact or work through CW API and it will interact with Chrome runtime to ensure that there is consistency and what ever gaps are present is filled by CW.

As we can see in below architecture diagram, it still talks with Chrome runtime, so it wouldn't change any runtime rules apart from UI based rule or APIs etc., and at-least it would not change any storage rule or underlying mechanism.

There are issues related to local storage access with CW, but those issues are related to API, **so as per me you can expect same storage mechanism, limits and rules with CW.**

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Ah OK. I was hoping it works in isolation as all or at least big parts of the Chrome code are packed when using Crosswalk. I guess I have to test it.

Comment: @BenjaminE. did you manage to test this? Do the same storage quota rules apply in indexeddb with crosswalk as per standard Chrome?

Comment: Sorry haven't tested it but would be interested if you do :) CW packs the Chrome runtime into the app package so I would expect (hope) them to modify the limits for extended capabilities.