# Will my apps lose localStorage data if Crosswalk updates it's internal browser?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, crosswalk

Recently I adopted cordova's [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) plugin to ensure a uniform and performant HTML5 environment across android devices. Everything was working fine until I deploy the application. That's when I noticed that all existing settings from the native browser, which was being used by the cordova webview were gone! Our localStorage was now in a different browser - **the chromium browser** which is served by crosswalk project.

Now I'm asking myself what will happen if the crosswalk project updates it's internal browser to a new chromium browser version? Will I lose the localStorage data once again?

**Here are some references that I had look at while researching into the subject:**

- [Crosswalk storage limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840649/crosswalk-storage-limits)
- [Scope of sessionStorage and localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742395/scope-of-sessionstorage-and-localstorage)
- [Where the sessionStorage and localStorage stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that was concerning this subject was closed last week.  **"Not able to migrate the existing webview data (localstorage/websql) to crosswalk"**

Check it out here: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-7368

Answer (score 1):

Probably yes, you will lose the data. Also updating the device SO can cause the loss of data. I had the same problem. You should consider to use sqlite database to persist permanently your data.

Comment: That was exactly what I was planning to do if the answer to my question was positive. The only thing that concerns me is that SQLite is also connected to browser isn't it? Or did you mean using https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin for that purpose?

Comment: WebSQL is "connected" to the browser. But to use SQLite you need a plugin like that you mentioned.